# Bytes of floating point number in C

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

I'm reading Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (Bryant & O'Hallaron).
In chapter 2 figure 2.4 it shows the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_float(float x) {
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}

void show_pointer(void *x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(void *));
}
```

*Figure 2.4 Code to print the byte representation of program objects. This code uses
casting to circumvent the type system. Similar functions are easily defined for other data
types*

Then using the following method

```
void test_show_bytes(int val) {
int ival = val;
float fval = (float) ival;
int *pval = &ival;
show_int(ival);
show_float(fval);
show_pointer(pval);
}
```

According to the book, this test method should print the following on linux 64 if the value is 12345

```
39 30 00 00
00 e4 40 46
b8 11 e5 ff ff 7f 00 00
```

However when I run the code I get the following result

```
39 30 00 00
00 00 00 00
d8 d6 54 c3 fd 7f 00 00
```

I'm using gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
The code that I'm running based on the examples from the book
I'm pretty new to C, any ideas why my results are different?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

nt main(){
  int val =  12345;
  test_show_bytes(val);
}

void test_show_bytes(int val) {
  int ival = val;
  float fval = (float) ival;
  int *pval = &ival;
  show_int(ival);
  show_float(fval);
  show_pointer(pval);
}


void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_float(float x) {
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}

void show_pointer(void *x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(void *));
}
```

Comment: Don't you get a load of warnings regarding functions being declared implicitely? If not, enable more warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can do this with command line options `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Does that book really put `main` and `show_all_bytes` above all the other funcions? Try putting it below them.

Comment: Aside: Each of the 3 show functions could be replaced with the same `show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show_float(fval);` is used before seeing the function definition of `show_float(float x)` - a no-no.  Don't do that. Enable all compiler warnings to be more productive.

Compiler guessed  the definition as `show_float(double x)` and so passed the wrong information during the `show_float(fval);` call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, solved.

Yes I had a lot of warnings about implicit declaration of functions and conflicting types.
I'm pretty much blind to anything under Error level logs, my bad.
I will check out what default argument promotion means in C
Putting function declarations in order solved the problem. I just guessed the place of the main function initially. Stupid guess, I have used main() only in OOP languages before, should have read the documentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_float(float x) {
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}

void show_pointer(void *x){
  show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(void *));
}

void test_show_bytes(int val) {
  int ival = val;
  float fval = (float) ival;
  int *pval = &ival;
  show_int(ival);
  show_float(fval);
  show_pointer(pval);
}

int main(){
  int val =  12345;
  test_show_bytes(val);
}
```